# Conformal mapping of C \ D* onto C \ (-1, 1)

Tags: cv.complex-variables, reference-request

Which is the concrete formula for the conformal mapping (normalized at infinity),
acting from $\mathbb C \backslash D^*$ onto

$\mathbb C\backslash[-1, 1]$?

Here $\mathbb C$ denotes the set of all complex numbers and  $D^*$  denotes the closed unit disk of the complex plane.

Also, I would be interested in references containing many examples of such of conformal 
mappings, by replacing the interval $[-1, 1]$ with other various subsets of the complex
plane.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find this information in almost any complex analysis book.

Comment: In more detail: compose the Koebe function http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/KoebeFunction.html with an appropriate Moebius transformation

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that the conformal mapping is given by the formula
f(z)=(1/2)(z + 1/z). Thanks any whay.